# Installing SunJCE on Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

The company I work for is wary of Android app development because the default cryptography library, Bouncy Castle, is not FIPS-140 certified.  Nothing I can do to change their minds or policies.

I'm wondering what options I have for installing (or at least bundling) SunJCE with my app.

For one, I can't find where I would download the latest version of this jar.  I tried grabbing the jce jar from my desktop and setting it as an internal jar in my Android project and received this amusing, if ominous, message:

> Attempt to include a core class
>   (java.* or javax.*) in something other
>   than a core library. It is likely that
>   you have attempted to include in an
>   application the core library (or a
>   part thereof) from a desktop virtual
>   machine. This will most assuredly not
>   work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
>   compatibility of your app with future
>   versions of the platform. It is also
>   often of questionable legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core
>   library -- which is only appropriate
>   as part of creating a full virtual
>   machine distribution, as opposed to
>   compiling an application -- then use
>   the "--core-library" option to
>   suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use
>   "--core-library" but are in fact
>   building an application, then be
>   forewarned that your application will
>   still fail to build or run, at some
>   point. Please be prepared for angry
>   customers who find, for example, that
>   your application ceases to function
>   once they upgrade their operating
>   system. You will be to blame for this
>   problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some
>   code that happens to be in a core
>   package, then the easiest safe
>   alternative you have is to repackage
>   that code. That is, move the classes
>   in question into your own package
>   namespace. This means that they will
>   never be in conflict with core system
>   classes. If you find that you cannot
>   do this, then that is an indication
>   that the path you are on will
>   ultimately lead to pain, suffering,
>   grief, and lamentation.

I'm not one for pain, suffering, grief, OR lamentation, so I'd like to know the proper way to go about this task, provided it's something I should attempt at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to import `java.*` or `javax.*` classes, due to the compiler error you encountered. Following their instructions should work, but changing the packages for something the size of JCE may be significant, and I don't know if the result would still qualify as FIPS-140. Plus, if JCE is implemented in pure Java, it may be slow on Android. And unless the JCE is from the GPL'd version of Java, or some other open source implementation, the licensing issue the error message hints at is relevant.

There are other FIPS-140 encryption libraries available, such as [NSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Security_Services), that have Java bindings, and others that you could probably write Java bindings for. It is possible you could get one of those working with the NDK to run on Android.